# Updating UITableView Information Externally (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I checked out an app the other day (Rutter's) and it had a tab in it's tab bar controller called "Deals." They update the deals once or twice a week and they show up in the app for people to use. It's in a table view.

How do you update information for an app after the app has been created and uploaded (particularly a table view)? I've tried to Google it but have no idea what to even search for. Where does the app get it's external information from? I don't need a full explanation if it's really complicated, just an idea of what to search for and read up on. Thanks!

P.S. I'm assuming this is also the way an online magazine or journal works with their iPhone app (in the way that they when they put a new article up on their site it immediately populates on the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as my knowledge whenever they are opening the app,then it is connecting to the server and get the information .Once getting the information you can display in any format.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was what was going on. I guess I'm wondering how to begin formatting that (the syntax display information from a server in a UITableView). That's what I'd like to get started on, I need a bit more detail.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial.This is related to connecting to a server.Once you have connected you are getting updated data.And then display it.

Answer (score 1):

They probably just send an http request, then format the results into a table view.  Some apps even use a cached webkit view instead of fancy native UI.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured (http request), but what is the syntax when formatting it into a table view. I'm having trouble searching for information on that.